# How to mock DOCUMENT dependency injection in jest Unit test?

Tags: angular, jasmine, jestjs

I have implemented component called 'A' which has dependency on document object.
component also has one method called onClose() which use document object service to get element using queryselector().

```
component A{
constructor(@inject(DOCUMENT) private document:document){}

onClose(){
this.element = this.document.querySelector(
      '.abc'
    ).parentNode;
}
}
```

my unit test code is like this :-

```
const mockDocument = {
    querySelector: (val): any => {
      return [
        {
          parentNode: val
        }
      ];
    }
  };
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [{ provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: mockDocument }]
});
}));
```

I am getting error

> this._doc.querySelectorAll is not a function

Can anyone please suggest where problem exist ?
Is there any problem with mock of particular injection token?

Comment: use `beforeEach(() => {` and not `beforeEach(async(() => {` and see if the unit test works?

Answer (score 0):

If you notice the error says `this._doc.querySelectorAll` but you have only mocked out the `querySelector` method. If you mock the `querySelectorAll` method as well it should work.

Comment: I had only used querySelector in my code ,never used querySelectorAll  method that's why I have not added in my mock.

Comment: @AdityaVashishtha I'm not 100% sure, but it's possible that TestBed uses the document internally and by overwriting it with a mock you are messing up it's internal behaviour. You would have to check the stack trace from the error to see where the call to querySelectorAll is being made. Are you using Jest or Karma? In Karma, I don't think you should need to mock the document because the tests are running in a browser.

Comment: I am using jest instead of karma,I checked code I m using dom method queryselector() only at specified method,not using any other method.

Comment: @AdityaVashishtha What happens if you remove the mock provider? Does it work? Jest runs jsdom out of the box and so all the DOM apis should work without the need to mock it in your tests. I have a feeling that TestBed is already providing the document object.

Comment: when I remove it and run the test it again gives me error for line where I used querySelector() method and if I spy on this method and provide mock implementation then I am not sure but next test cases are breaking even if it is empty it() ,it will give error that "parent.appendChild is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeEach(() => {
  querySelectorMock = jasmine.createSpy('querySelector').and.callFake(mockDocument.querySelector);
  const doc = TestBed.inject(DOCUMENT);
  doc.querySelector = querySelectorMock;
```

Something like this solve this issue for me (I did not mock DOCUMENT in configureTestingModule)

Answer (score 0):

If you have errors like:
`The selector "#root0" did not match any elements` or
`this._doc.querySelectorAll is not a function` or similar.

Solution:

```
  let mockedDocument: Document;
  const mockedElement: Element = jasmine.createSpyObj('element', ['scrollIntoView']);
  ...
  mockedDocument = TestBed.inject(DOCUMENT);
  ...
  spyOn(mockedDocument, 'querySelector').and.returnValue(mockedElement);
```

Do not rewrite `DOCUMENT`'s methods. Just use `spyOn`.